# I want to send a parcel to some one "care of"

Tags: phrase-request

How do I address a parcel "care of"? Is it as simple as "curator di"? I wish to send some books to a ristorante for the Owens as I don't know their home address.

Comment: Usually we say “presso”. And welcome!

Comment: I second egreg's “presso”, and moreover the abbreviation “c/o” is also often used in Italy. “Curator di”, on the other hand, doesn't mean anything in this context.

Answer (score 4):

As correctly pointed out by @egreg and @DaG you can say ***presso*** or ***c/o***.

The latter is usually used in addresses as an abbreviation.

Moreover, you can address it with the expression ***alla cortese attenzione di*** meaning you're sending the parcel to a place where many people work.

The receiver will so be able to dispatch it properly.

Comment: Yes, but this is just one possible way of saying it.